# AS3 | How to add TextField in a button when that button is clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, text, click

When I click the `btn1` `button`, I want the `txt` `TextField` to be added to it as in, the text of the `btn1` `button` should be the text in the `textField`.

```
 import flash.ui.Mouse;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import flash.text.TextField;

 var txt:TextField = new TextField;
 txt.text = "Click here to find MH370";
 addChild(txt);


 btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(event:MouseEvent):void{

     this.addChild(txt);

 });
```

`btn1` is an instance of `btn1` `button` `Symbol`

And am getting the ERROR:

> ```
> TypeError: Error #1006: addChild is not a function.
>   at MethodInfo-1()
> ```

What am I doing Wrong?

See my Work Are:

[image]

The ACTION SCRIPT:
[image]

To SEE Images Large: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKE2Q.jpg ***and*** https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwHmT.jpg

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

var txt:TextField = new TextField;
txt.text = "Click here to find MH370";

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(event:MouseEvent):void{

     (btn1.upState as DisplayObjectContainer).addChild(txt);

});
```

Comment: Sure thanks for your time.... I will indeed look into the article... I highly appreciate your being their to assist... thanx again!!!

Comment: Not yet.... still fighting... but thanks for the link. Once i get something done, i'll hv u informed.. tx again

Comment: Am still getting an Error... but what I think is the CODE: `((btn1.upState as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildAt(1) as TextField).text = "New text";` assumes that the `txt` is already a child of `btn1` if am not wrong.... The Problem is, when the CODE is run, txt, is not yet a child of btn1. How do you make. `txt` a Child of `btn1`? so that we can use :`getChildAt(1) as TextField)`

Comment: Thanx again.... Though with the update,  I got this Error: `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()` ...

Comment: I cant really tell which line... but the error only came after adding the update u provided: See full code in Paste Bin: http://pastebin.com/KYqYbQcj

Comment: Sure UpDated...  It says. OnClick: `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at MethodInfo-1()
` See my NewPasteBin... Thnx again!           http://pastebin.com/qEZqGtLT

Comment: I try together with the for loop?

Comment: Sure, the Debugger said it is not compatible with my OS am using win8.1 which link do i download?

Comment: Whats the `KB2867622` for??... the Link is downloading that thing... ByTheWay I added some Images

Comment: By looking at those pictures... do you spot something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should get the line number. Try to test it in the browser. Please clear the comments, it is getting a bit messy.